# how can i have date range for datepicker (date field) - when submitting form sharepoint list 2013

Tags: list, javascript, datepicker

When users are selecting a date i want the date to be between a range. e.g they can only select from 1st jan to 2nd march nothing else.
Is there a way to be able to add this into the date field?

Comment: In that case you can you some custom datepicker rather than using default SP datepicker.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the OOTB datefields you could probably just change the `minjday` and `maxjday` for the picker, but that only restricts the picker. They could still write a date that is not in the picker range, for that you'll have to add a change handler to the field. There is also a property called `onvaluesetfrompicker` if i remember correctly that could be used.

Simple example for restricting the picker:

```
var getSPDayDiff = function(date) {
    return Math.round(Math.abs( ( new Date(1601,0,1).getTime() - date.getTime())/( 24*60*60*1000 ) ) );
}

var minDay = getSPDayDiff( new Date(2015,0,1) );
var maxDay = getSPDayDiff( new Date(2015,2,2) );                

var $trDateTimeControl = $("input[id='"+ g_strDateTimeControlIDs["SPDateField1"] + "']").closest("tr");

var dateTimeHtml = $trDateTimeControl.find(".ms-dtinput:eq(1)").html();
dateTimeHtml = dateTimeHtml.replace("minjday=109207", "minjday="+minDay);
dateTimeHtml = dateTimeHtml.replace("maxjday=2666269", "maxjday="+maxDay);

$trDateTimeControl.find(".ms-dtinput:eq(1)").html( dateTimeHtml );
```

`minjday` and `maxjday` are number of days sine 1/1/1601.

Comment: Hi Anders can i use this on an infopath form?

Comment: For InfoPath I don't know @naijacoder

Comment: I also have requirement where i should disable the pastdates and also current date in date picker ,allowing user to pick the date that is not less than today.
[![sharepoint date time control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjyby.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjyby.png) when i inspect the element of date icon i seen following code:
a **onclick**="**clickDatePicker**("ctl00_ctl39_g_1520de65_6f70_4c7f_b7b2_5578a563acda_ff241_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_startDateTimeControl_startDateTimeControlDate", "\u002fsites\u002fPSEGPublishingsite\u002f_layouts\u002f15\u002fiframe.aspx?&cal=1&lcid=1033&langid=1033&ww=011

Comment: @SwethaParitala Please if you have a new question you can post it [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)